# knexfile.js does not read Dotenv variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js, dotenv

So I am trying out knexjs and the first setup works like a charm. I've set up my connection, created a datastructure and in my terminal i ran `$ knex migrate:latest.`
It all worked fine... the migrated tables showed up in my database ran the migrate again and got `Already up to date`.

Now here is where I get an issue: Using Dotenv... Here is my code:

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {

        development: {

            client: process.env.DB_CLIENT,
            connection: {

                host: process.env.DB_HOST,

                user: process.env.DB_ROOT,
                password: process.env.DB_PASS,

                database: process.env.DB_NAME,
                charset: process.env.DB_CHARSET

            }
        }
};
```

As far as i can see nothing wrong with it and when i run the script through node no errors show up.
Then I wanted to check if I still could do a migrate and i get the following error:

> Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'[MY IP]'
>   (using password: YES)

I am using the same vars only this time from my `.env` file. But when i look at the error nothing is loaded from it, and yes both the `knexfile.js` and `.env` are in the root of my project :) Among the things i tried is setting the path in different ways within `require('dotenv').config();` but then it would throw an error from dotenv meaning the file was already correctly loaded.

Can anyone help me figuring this out?

Comment: improval suggestion: please post the command line you used to run your script.

Comment: it is in there: `$ knex migrate:latest` (added markdown)

Comment: Please add those debug prints to this which I suggested in the github issue. Also I suppose you are not running this in docker nor through npm scripts, but straight from command line with `knex migrate:latest`?

Comment: Yup I’m using the terminal in visual studio code. The debug prints didn’t add any info sadly. Still thnx for your reply and advice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after some trial and error i finally figured out what was wrong. I don't know what caused it but somehow the install of Knex wasn't done properly...

I un- and reinstalled Knex (local and global). Then first I installed it on the global level and than as a dependency. After that I initialized Knex again ( `$ knex init` ) and started from the ground up.

I think, but i am still not sure why because i could not find any info about it, the order of installing Knex matters (or mattered in my case and i am not even sure what i did wrong the first time).

#### On the side

If you are new to Knex and just blindly follow a random tutorial/article and just create a new file for Knex (i.e. knexfile.js), Knex will still work but other packages could fail to execute properly. This is what i don't see in most articles i found, read the documentation on how to generate the files needed (migrations and seeds). Most articles don't cover these steps properly.

Hope this is worth anything